# Blogdown not displaying plots

Tags: r, blogdown

I have my blogdown site that has been running for a while. When writing a post today I cannot get plots to render when running `serve_site()`.

The plot generates fine when running the .Rmd in interactive mode, it's only when being built by knitting/serve_site/build_site that it doesn't work. The image below shows what I see on the webpage - just that small icon in the bottom.

[image]

I know these questions have come up a lot, so just to list the things I've tried:

1. There is no `.gitignore` under the `static` directory
2. I've set `[markup.goldmark.renderer]unsafe = true`  in the `config.toml`
3. I've checked that the figures are being generated (I can see the files under `index_files/figure-html`)

You can see my blog source [here](https://github.com/condwanaland/A-Sky-Full-of-Data)

And the (not working) webpage [here](https://conorneilson.com/post/two-new-data-packages/)

Comment: Not an answer but there's another bug: all 5 points of the enumerated list after the title **phonewar** are numbered **1.**

Comment: I just figured it out and please see details here: https://github.com/condwanaland/A-Sky-Full-of-Data/pull/6

Comment: Thank you for this post!
https://github.com/condwanaland/A-Sky-Full-of-Data/blob/2f4fb4292bdf617fac4fbc6206fdb6845c8e0bef/config.toml#L26-L29

Is what fixed it for me